# Cannot ssh to laptop with OSX hostname.local, but can connect through ip

Tags: macos, ssh, hostname

I am trying to connect from my server to my macbook thru ssh but I cannot find its hostname on the network.  I enabled *Remote Login* in **System Preferences > Sharing** and my mac claims that:

```
Computers on your local network can access your computer at: macbook.local
```

Yet when I try to connect via `ssh wdkrnls@macbook.local` it tells me:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname macbook.local: Name or service not known
```

But I can ssh into it when I type in the given IP address (ie.  `ssh wdkrnls@192.168.1.15`).  The trouble is that this IP address changes and I want to add a remote git repository over ssh, so this won't do.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What OS is your server? If it's not Mac OS X then you need to install Avahi and set the following in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
hosts:    files dns mdns
```

OR

```
hosts:    files mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns
```

Comment: I'm using Archlinux on my server and I added the [lines from the Arch wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Avahi) for avahi into `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and it worked!  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

What operating system is your server running? It needs to support Bonjour aka mDNS, the technology that powers the .local hostname. You can find out more about mDNS [here](http://www.multicastdns.org/). There are a variety of mDNS implementations for UNIX, Linux, and Windows. I recommend both Apple's mDNSResponder and the open-source Avahi deamon for Unix-like systems.

If you already have mDNS on your server, then I'd recommend looking at your network setup. mDNS cannot be used across certain VPN systems including L2TP/IPsec, nor can it he used across different subnets. The mDNS homepage has configuration directions to set up Wide-Area mDNS, which requires the use of a nameserver, but I have not succeeded with such efforts.

A simpler and easier approach might be to give your MacBook a static IP address. Most routers allow you to assign static IPs using either DHCP client IDs or the interface's MAC address.

I've been wrangling a few mDNS issues recently myself.